# Pygame on Yocto

Tags: python, pygame, yocto

I've been trying to install the python library for making games, pygame, in my yocto image of linux for my raspberry pi 2. I have a python code of a game, I've run it in raspbian and it runs pretty slow, but it runs. Now in my image of linux I already have python but I have failed in installing the pygame library. Every time I tried to run the game it says "Error: import pygame", so clearly the problem is in the way I install the library.
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I have the python 2.7 version installed in my image if that helps.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install pygame on your system? You say you're doing it, but not how, and the error you show just means it's not installed yet. Please describe what you're doing for the installation, and what happens when you do it (not when you try to run the pygame-using program afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your PYTHONPATH is set ?
To set it, do:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

You can add this line to your .profile or .bashrc